# No me funciona el background-image desde mi archivo css

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema con la propiedad "background-image" desde 
mi archivo css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ES">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, 
 shrink-to-fit=no">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Estilos.css">     
</head>
<body>

<div class="Fondo">
</div>

</body>
```

y este es mi css

```
.Fondo{
  background-image: url(img/Fondo_Error.png);
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 150px;
  }
```

desde el css el background-image no me funciona pero si lo pongo dentro de la etiqueta, recién me funciona.

```
<div class="Fondo" style="background-image: url(img/Fondo_Error.png);">

</div>
```

Cabe resaltar que el border y height si me funcionan desde el css.

Comment: Tienes los estilos en una carpeta llamada css, luego si llamas una imagen desde el css, tienes que hacerlo añadiendo ../ a la ruta, mientras que si lo haces desde el raíz, si está en el sitio correcto.

Comment: Muy amable ya me funciono , gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El archivo *Estilos.css* está en una carpeta llamada *css*, y el HTML esta en un directorio arriba del directorio CSS, con lo cual si pones en el CSS que la imagen de fondo va a ser una imagen que esta en el mismo directorio que el *Estilos.css*.

Tendrías que poner el siguiente código en tu CSS:

```css
.Fondo{
    background-image: url(../img/Fondo_Error.png);
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Ya que le estás indicando que la imagen *Fondo_Error.png* está en el directorio *img*, pero un directorio arriba de el directorio *css*.