# CSS INTERNO O CSS EXTERNO, INFLUYEN A LA HORA DE QUERER VER LA PAGINA WEB CREADA?

Tags: html, css, visualización-de-datos

La pregunta surgio a raiz de que al momento de realizar una web de proyecto simple en el entorno de desarrollo Visual Studio Code, me tope con que si colocaba el CSS INTERNO podia ver el sitio bien en mi navegador local por defecto, PERO al momento de crear el CSS EXTERNO las imagenes se dejaron de ver en mi navegador por defecto y se paso a verlas solamente con Visual Studio Code cuando hacia click derecho del mouse y elegir "open with live server"...Por que pasara esto? hay alguna forma que la pagina web se vea en ambos lados? o el css externo solo se ve en servidor nomas?

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Utiliza `**palabra**`  para dar énfasis. 2. Escribir en mayúsculas equivale a gritar, a nadie le gusta que le griten, ergo, edita la pregunta y aplica las correcciones por favor. 3. Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 4. Bienvenido a SOes. Saludos.

Comment: Por favor, proporciona detalles adicionales como parte del código que estas implementando para que podamos ver como ayudarte. Pueda que sean problemas con rutas u otros, pero sin código no podemos verificar nada.

Answer (score 2):

El error cometido fue que la ruta de las imágenes estaba errónea, cuando CSS EXTERNO se le coloco un:

```
#p1{
    background-image: url(imagenes/placa1.jpg);
    background-color: chocolate;
}
```

Y así buscaba en la carpeta css que contiene solamente el archivo **`style.css`** una carpeta imágenes que no estaba ahí... La carpeta imágenes se encontraba en el directorio raíz del proyecto.

Para llegar a esta había que retroceder un directorio para esto se requería agregar **`../`** (Esto retrocede en el directorio llegando a la carpeta raíz del proyecto) y quedaría así `background-image: url(../imagenes/placa1.jpg)`, al agregar esto en la ruta url se soluciono...

Cabe destacar 2 links que me ayudaron a la resolución de esto:

- Por un lado un post de acá:
  [No me funciona el background-image desde mi archivo css](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160134/no-me-funciona-el-background-image-desde-mi-archivo-css)
- Por el otro un video de youtube que me amplio el panorama:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVm3tmxQk9c